# (How do I solve this formula?) Formula for Rounded Corners

Tags: geometry, education

I'm learning how to properly design app icons for iOS. A portion of this requires some knowledge in a formula that I've never seem before. Below is an image of the formula I'm trying to solve. For me, math is something I struggle with. How would I solve this? What are the lines around the $x$ and number? I believe the size (width $\times$ height) is what is input into the $x$. Is this something that I can solve using a calculator?

I've also seen the formula in this form $x^4+y^4=r^4$. Is this the same formula in the photo?

[image: Image of formula]

(Continued)

I tried the following $|\frac{120}{60}|^5+|\frac{120}{60}|^5$ and got $64$. Seems really high and actually isn't the radii I'm looking for. Any thoughts?

Comment: those lines are absolute value bars (usually function $abs$ in programming). The formula in the image is different from $x^4+y^4=r^4$

Comment: Thank Vasya for your reply. In the formula I used on paper `|120/60|^5+|120/60|^5` is that the correct output or should I be getting a different number?

Comment: @miler: see my answer. But $x^4+y^4=r^4$ will also work, just corners will be more rounded.

Comment: @Vasya I'm still getting a very high number. Which tells me I'm doing looking at this wrong. So, if I do `120^4+120^4` I should get the radius? Is that the entire shape or for each corner?

Comment: In which sense do you want to "solve" this, and why? If you want to use it in an app, you'd be more interested in [how to draw it programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389114/draw-ios-7-style-squircle-programatically).

Comment: Variables $x$ and $y$ in that formula must be comprised between $-60$ and $60$. As a result, you'll obtain a quasi-square of width $120$. If you need a larger square, you must accordingly change $60$ in the formula.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the formula to create the image on the paper is $|x^5|+|y^5|=1$ because when $y=0$, $x=1$. You need to express $y$ in terms of $x$:

for $0 \le x \le 1$ it will be  $$y=\pm\sqrt[5]{1-x^5}$$
for $-1 \le x \le 0$ it will be  $$y=\pm\sqrt[5]{1+x^5}$$

Varying $x$ from $-1$ to $1$ and calculating $y$ you'll get points for your drawing.

Comment: I'm still a little confused by that. Varying is just increasing the value y by 1, right? I'm getting a really large number if I apply that to the formula.

Comment: Here's what I'm playing with on WolframAlpha https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7C1024%2F60%7C%5E5%2B%7C-1025%2F60%7C%5E5